# Apple Test Flight and External Testing Emails Requirements

Tags: testflight

When I add external users to Apple's Test Flight they seem to only get an email if the email address is associated with an iOS device. From the documentation it appears to me that they should be able to receive the invite anywhere, but they would have to open up Test Flight and "redeem" the coupon on the device they want to test one.

I have checked our spam filter at our company and the invites are not being caught there.

Are there rules for what email addresses can be used for External Testers in Test Flight?

Thank you.